# Micrometer | Why CompositeMeterRegistry manages Set of Registry instead List/LinkedHashSet?

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am using Micrometer project for publishing metrics in my spring boot 2.x application.

I have implemented two `MeterRegistry`(`StepMeterRegistry` and `SimpleMeterRegistry`) so spring boot internally creates `CompositeMeterRegistry` having a set of StepMeterRegistry and SimpleMeterRegistry.

Now, I am using `/actuator/metrics` endpoint for viewing current metrics count.

Implementation of `MetricsEndpoint` is like:
 - It will fetch the **first registry from compositeMeterRegistry** and displays metrics.

so now the issue is below:
- `compositeMeterRegistry` manages set so the order is not guaranteed, but I want to publish `SimpleMeterRegistry` only for `'/actuator/metrics'` endpoint.

A current workaround I followed is creating @Primary bean for MetricsEndpoint and provided SimpleMeterRegistry.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint(SimpleMeterRegistry registry) {
    return new MetricsEndpoint(registry);
}
```

As micrometer is now managed by Spring, why don't they kept **List or LinkedHashSet of registry** in CompositeMeterRegistry. It would be easy to use for developers.

Comment: Suppose it were a `LinkedHashSet`, then it seems like more or less the same criticism remains: why does the output of `/actuator/metrics` favor the first inserted over the other? Feels arbitrary either way. `/actuator/metrics` was meant as a kind of cheap diagnostic tool only.

Comment: I agree that `/acutator/metrics` is a cheap diagnostic tool. I would recommend extending the `MetricsEndpoint` and manually pass in the `MeterRegistry` you want exposed (which is pretty much the solution you went with).

Comment: @jkschneider I don't think the same criticism remains.
Any implementation should behave the same over the restart if nothing is changed. 

Current implementation gives metrics from either of meterRegistry whicheve will posisioned first.